# Python Pandas Dataframe Plot: setting axis and legend font size and xtick spacing

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

In Python 2.7, I am attempting to plot (line plot) the columns of a pandas dataframe as subplots in one figure, with the columns representing a time series of prices for different products.  This can be easily done using the df.plot command as shown below.  However, I am finding it impossible to find a way to control axis and legend font size and xtick spacing.  Is there a good alternative to get this done?

```
df.plot(subplots=True, layout=(numrows,numcols),sharex=True)
plt.show()
```

The key here is that the script takes in a dataframe that on each run will have a different number of columns, and so it isn't practical to attempt to specify these settings line by line for each plot using subplots, as the number of columns will be different on each run of the script.[image]

Comment: You can look into: https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html

Comment: I guess this is too broad. Of course you may control everything you want using the usual matplotlib tools available. Concerning "axis and legend font size" you will easily find a solution. Concerning tick-spacing you won't because this is controlled by the pandas locator, which is not campatible with matplotlib date locators.